# Excel VBA Event - AutoFilter Button clicked

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

To overcome the *Protection Limitation* of Autofiltered ranges (see my Answer to: [VBA Excel - How to lock specific cells but allow filtering and sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197772/vba-excel-how-to-lock-specific-cells-but-allow-filtering-and-sorting/55395618#55395618)) I have a desire to respond to the user clicking an Autofilter Button (at which point I can unprotect the sheet and allow the filtering).  I can't find any event that triggers when the user clicks an autofilter button so instead I have instructed my users to first select an Autofilter row's cell (an event I can recognize) before clicking the cell's Autofilter button.

This is a mostly-reasonable workround but it does require the users to work in a non-standard way.  Is there any way to capture that an autofilter button (on a locked cell) has been clicked?

Many thanks

Comment: you have a button which runs code... why can you not tell that code to indicate something globally to trigger?

Comment: Thanks cyril that was a quick response.  But it's not my button, rather it's the Excel Autofilter button.  You know, the one you get if you select a row then click the "Filter" button in the "Data" menu.

Comment: Why doesn't ticking EnableAutofilter when protecting doesnot work for you?

Comment: I know this is an old thread but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982509/excel-vba-detect-ok-event-from-autofilter) could help.